# Some hints on mpi_gatherv

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to understand mpi_gatherv through a simple example:

each rank has an array called x_local of size "id+1" thus rank 1 has x_local(1), rank 2 has x_local(2) and so on. In total I am using 4 procs.

For simplicity x_local = real(id+1)

On output I would like to have an array x (only for the root processor) like this:

`x=(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)`

**Here is my code:**

```
    subroutine testGatherV

    ! Global variables

    use mpi
    use mpivar

    ! Local variables

    implicit none

    integer i, ierr, displs(nid), rcounts(nid)

    real, dimension(:), allocatable:: x_local

    real, dimension(:), allocatable:: x

    allocate(x_local(id+1))

    allocate(x(10))

   ! 

    x=-1.0

    displs(1) = 0
    displs(2) = 1
    displs(3) = 3
    displs(4) = 6

    rcounts(1) = 1
    rcounts(2) = 2
    rcounts(3) = 3
    rcounts(4) = 4

    x_local = real(id+1)

    call mpi_gatherv(x_local, id+1, MPI_REAL, x, rcounts, displs, &
            MPI_REAL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    if(id.eq.0)  write(*,*) 'x = ', x

    end
```

**The output is:**

```
 x =    0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000       -1.0000000000000000       -1.0000000000000000       -1.0000000000000000       -1.0000000000000000       -1.0000000000000000
```

Where am I wrong? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! please always include a [MCVE], especially when the error is very likely in the code you are not sharing (fwiw, I created my own program based on this one, and got the expected output).

Comment: Hi Gilles, thank you for your replay. The code seems correct, I have found out that using MPI_REAL8 as type fixed the problem! This is because i was compiling with real 8 flag.

Comment: If you chose to compile with this flag, then the right thing to do is to rebuild your MPI library with the same flag (so you can keep using `MPI_REAL` with the `real` FORTRAN type and keep your code portable)

Comment: The right thing to do is not to use the "real 8" flag at all and type and kind your variables correctly. Not doing so is just asking for a life of pain. And it's spelt Fortran.